# Use of さらに with 敬語

Tags: grammar, reading-comprehension

From the following:

いつも（会社名前）をご愛用いただき、ありがとうございます。

さて、弊社では、お客様がプリンター用インクを追加購入なさる際に、定価の５％割引でお求めいただいておりますが、この７、８月中に購入のお申込みをされたお客様には、さらにお得な特別
割引価値でお届けいたします。この機会にご利用いただければ幸いです。詳しくはホームページをご覧ください。

my understanding is that :
customers are currently buying ink from our company at 5% discount, **but** (インクを追加購入なさる際に、定価の５％割引でお求めいただいております**が**)

if you buy in 7,8 月, we will provide it at an **even better** price (この７、８月中に購入のお申込みをされたお客様には、**さらに**お得な特別
割引価値でお届けいたします)

So this is an exam question, and basically that's apparently wrong and the meaning of this email is:  if you buy in 7, 8 月, then you get a 5% discount.

But doesn't the the use of お求めいただいております show people are already buying it? (iteimasu)? And doesn't さらに mean that what follows kind of goes further than what was stated before?

Answer (score 2):

*Your* understanding is correct. This さらに simply modifies お得な right after it, and it means "at an *even* better price" (than the current 5% discount). さらに has nothing to do with 敬語, although it does sound more formal than もっと.

This お求めいただいております is the progressive form. The letter says that the customers are currently buying ink at 5% discount, but the price will be even better in July and August.